# How to start activity with a bitmap attached?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 startActivity(intent);
```

which successfully launches an Messaging App on android.

But how can i attach a Bitmap object when launching the intent?

I have read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html,
the closet thing to what i need is EXTRA_STREAM, like this:
intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, _uri);

but my case, I have a reference of Bitmap object, not an URI of an
Bitmap.

Please tell me what can I do to attach a Bitmap object?

Thank you.

Comment: **You can see the answer here:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-1-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0):

I'm having kind of the same problem. I tried this:

```
intent.putExtra("image", image);
```

But when I ran the program, it couldn't launch the new activity. It looked like the system was stuck at this point. The UI was not rendered but a black screen instead. I waited for a while and it asked me whether I wanted to force quit.

In short, how to we pass Bitmap data between activities?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```