# How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, bitmap, parcelable

In my activity, I create a `Bitmap` object and then I need to launch another `Activity`,
How can I pass this `Bitmap` object from the sub-activity (the one which is going to be launched)?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable`, so you could always pass it with the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: If the bitmap exists as a file or a resource, its is always better to pass the `URI` or `ResourceID` of the bitmap and not the bitmap itself. Passing the entire bitmap requires a lot of memory. Passing the URL requires very little memory and allows each activity to load and scale the bitmap as they need it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but this one do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android

Comment: @slayton how do we pass images as URI / ResourceIDs? example? thanks!

Comment: putting bitmap on extra like that, is not a best practice, if the bitmap object size is bigger, then you get "java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy......".
the recommended way is like @slayton says, you have to save bitmap on external storage and pass just the URI.

Comment: what is max size of bitmap that can be passed?

Comment: `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` thrown with this.

Comment: @AtifSayings The limit is 1MB. It's better not to pass bitmaps with intents.

Answer (score 25):

Actually, passing a bitmap as a Parcelable will result in a "JAVA BINDER FAILURE" error.  Try passing the bitmap as a byte array and building it for display in the next activity.

I shared my solution here:
[how do you pass images (bitmaps) between android activities using bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles/7890405#7890405)

Answer (score 23):

Passsing bitmap as parceable in bundle between activity is not a good idea because of size limitation of Parceable(1mb). You can store the bitmap in a file in internal storage and retrieve the stored bitmap in several activities. Here's some sample code.

To store bitmap in a file **myImage** in internal storage:

```
public String createImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fileName = "myImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close file output
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fileName = null;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Then in the next activity you can decode this file myImage to a bitmap using following code:

```
//here context can be anything like getActivity() for fragment, this or MainActivity.this
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.openFileInput("myImage"));
```

**Note** A lot of checking for null and scaling bitmap's is ommited.

Comment: This will not compile - cannot resolve method `openFileOutput`.

Comment: use this.openFileOutput() if you are in activity or requireActivity.openFileOutput() if you are in a fragment

Answer (score 5):

If the image is too large and you can't save&load it to the storage, you should consider just using a global static reference to the bitmap (inside the receiving activity), which will be reset to null on onDestory, only if "isChangingConfigurations" returns true.

Answer (score 5):

## Compress and Send `Bitmap`

**The accepted answer will crash when the `Bitmap` is too large.** I believe it's a **1MB** limit. The `Bitmap` must be compressed into a different file format such as a **JPG** represented by a `ByteArray`, then it can be safely passed via an `Intent`.

## Implementation

The function is contained in a separate thread using **Kotlin Coroutines** because the `Bitmap` compression is chained after the `Bitmap` is created from an url `String`. The `Bitmap` creation requires a separate thread in order to avoid **Application Not Responding (ANR)** errors.

#### Concepts Used

- **Kotlin Coroutines** [notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xANxIeduaDMR2ZTZ9efkHf7YXyLs4osGnXp9odNgQNE/edit?rm=minimal).
- The **Loading, Content, Error (LCE)** pattern is used below. If interested you can learn more about it in [this talk and video](https://hackernoon.com/android-unidirectional-flow-with-livedata-bf24119e747).
- **LiveData** is used to return the data. I've compiled my favorite **LiveData** resource in [these notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e3Y126VbuZRX1-C4iKSQlFy3sfnBPkwLriDGXV9EKEU/edit?rm=minimal).
- In *Step 3*, `toBitmap()` is a [Kotlin extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) requiring that library to be added to the app dependencies.

### Code

#### 1. Compress `Bitmap` to **JPG** `ByteArray` after it has been created.

*Repository.kt*

```
suspend fun bitmapToByteArray(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    MutableLiveData<Lce<ContentResult.ContentBitmap>>().apply {
        postValue(Lce.Loading())
        postValue(Lce.Content(ContentResult.ContentBitmap(
            ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
                try {                     
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(URL(url).openConnection().apply {
                        doInput = true
                        connect()
                    }.getInputStream())
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                   postValue(Lce.Error(ContentResult.ContentBitmap(ByteArray(0), "bitmapToByteArray error or null - ${e.localizedMessage}")))
                   null
                }?.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, BITMAP_COMPRESSION_QUALITY, this)
           }.toByteArray(), "")))
        }
    }
```

*ViewModel.kt*

```
//Calls bitmapToByteArray from the Repository
private fun bitmapToByteArray(url: String) = liveData {
    emitSource(switchMap(repository.bitmapToByteArray(url)) { lce ->
        when (lce) {
            is Lce.Loading -> liveData {}
            is Lce.Content -> liveData {
                emit(Event(ContentResult.ContentBitmap(lce.packet.image, lce.packet.errorMessage)))
            }
            is Lce.Error -> liveData {
                Crashlytics.log(Log.WARN, LOG_TAG,
                        "bitmapToByteArray error or null - ${lce.packet.errorMessage}")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

#### 2. Pass image as `ByteArray` via an `Intent`.

In this sample it's passed from a **Fragment** to a **Service**. It's the same concept if being shared between two **Activities**.

*Fragment.kt*

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(
    context!!,
    Intent(context, AudioService::class.java).apply {
        action = CONTENT_SELECTED_ACTION
        putExtra(CONTENT_SELECTED_BITMAP_KEY, contentPlayer.image)
    })
```

#### 3. Convert `ByteArray` back to `Bitmap`.

*Utils.kt*

```
fun ByteArray.byteArrayToBitmap(context: Context) =
    run {
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this, BITMAP_OFFSET, size).run {
            if (this != null) this
            // In case the Bitmap loaded was empty or there is an error I have a default Bitmap to return.
            else AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, ic_coinverse_48dp)?.toBitmap()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because Intent has size limit .
I use public static object to do pass bitmap from service to broadcast ....

```
public class ImageBox {
    public static Queue<Bitmap> mQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Bitmap>(); 
}
```

pass in my service

```
private void downloadFile(final String url){
        mExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap b = BitmapFromURL.getBitmapFromURL(url);
                synchronized (this){
                    TaskCount--;
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_ON_GET_IMAGE);
                ImageBox.mQ.offer(b);
                sendBroadcast(i);
                if(TaskCount<=0)stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }
```

My BroadcastReceiver

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver get broadcast");

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownLoadImageService.ACTION_ON_GET_IMAGE.equals(action)) {
                Bitmap b = ImageBox.mQ.poll();
                if(b==null)return;
                if(mListener!=null)mListener.OnGetImage(b);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be late but can help.
On the first fragment or activity do declare a class...for example

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        description des = new description();

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                constan.photoMap = bitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    }

public static class constan {
    public static Bitmap photoMap = null;
    public static String namePass = null;
}
```

Then on the second class/fragment do this..

```
Bitmap bm = postFragment.constan.photoMap;
final String itemName = postFragment.constan.namePass;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above solutions doesn't work for me, Sending bitmap as `parceableByteArray` also generates error `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size`.

**Solution**

1. Saved the bitmap in internal storage as:

```
public String saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String fileName = "ImageName";//no .png or .jpg needed
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            // remember close file output
            fo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fileName = null;
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

2. and send in `putExtra(String)` as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySketcher.this,ActivityEditor.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", saveBitmap(bmp));
startActivity(intent);
```

3. and Receive it in other activity as:

```
if(getIntent() != null){
  try {
           src = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openFileInput("myImage"));
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bitmap transfer. try this....

In the first class:

1) Create:

```
private static Bitmap bitmap_transfer;
```

2) Create getter and setter

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap_transfer() {
    return bitmap_transfer;
}

public static void setBitmap_transfer(Bitmap bitmap_transfer_param) {
    bitmap_transfer = bitmap_transfer_param;
}
```

3) Set the image:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.buildDrawingCache();
setBitmap_transfer(image.getDrawingCache());
```

Then, in the second class:

```
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img2);
imagem2.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), classe1.getBitmap_transfer()));
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the way mentioned above didn't worked for me. Every time I put the bitmap in the intent, the 2nd activity didn't start. The same happened when I passed the bitmap as byte[].

I followed this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2011/10/share-bitmap-between-activities-as.html) and it worked like a charme and very fast:

```
package your.packagename

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class CommonResources { 
      public static Bitmap photoFinishBitmap = null;
}
```

in my 1st acitiviy:

```
Constants.photoFinishBitmap = photoFinishBitmap;
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImageViewerActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and here is the onCreate() of my 2nd Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bitmap photo = Constants.photoFinishBitmap;
    if (photo != null) {
        mViewHolder.imageViewerImage.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work. I followed the link, and it appears you should have used `CommonResources.photoFinishBitmap` instead of `Constants.photoFinishBitmap`.

Comment: Bad practice. What will be happens with static field in the Activity class during recreation of the the whole process (for example, due to changing permissions for the app in runtime)? The answer is NPE.