# How to pass the byte image from one activity to another in android

Tags: android, image, android-activity, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass a Bitmap object from 1 activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-1-activity-to-another)

i am using a camera application in android. in my application im tried to pass the image that clicked to another activity. code as shown bellow,

```
 PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
               Intent i = new Intent(Hackbook.this, view.class);
                   i.putExtra("photo", data);
                   Log.d(TAG, "jpegCallback1" +data);
                  startActivity(i); 
        }
    };
```

and second activity view.java is,

```
setContentView(R.layout.view);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");
        Log.i(TAG, "jpegCallback2" + photo);
        Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (photo, 0, photo.length);
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

when i run this in emulator i got an image that inbuilt in the emulator. But when im tried to run this in my device there is no image displayed in the second activity. Logcat is shown bellow,

```
12-14 17:58:33.756: DEBUG/camera(630): jpegCallback1[B@44f90d60
12-14 17:58:33.785: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.facebook.android/.view (has extras) }
12-14 17:58:33.985: INFO/Camera(630): jpegCallback2[B@44f385e0
12-14 17:58:34.605: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.facebook.android/.view: 730 ms (total 730 ms)
12-14 18:00:56.351: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

If anyone know about this please help me....

Comment: make it static and access in second activity

Comment: Agree with Dr. nik, this is the best way to implement instead of passing extra.

Comment: Hi @Dr.nik, I dont know how to make that byte data to static. could u explain that?

Comment: @Binu  Google is your friend please ask him.. and if you got any trouble then ask me

Answer (score 0):

```
possible duplicate answer
```

try to pass bitmap object using intent object like this way

```
Intent i = new Intent(Hackbook.this, view.class);
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (data, 0, photo.length);
i.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
startActivity(i);
```

and retrieve time do this way

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2459624/760489

Comment: This could be a comment i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply name you Bitmap as static first.

```
 public static Bitmap bitmap;
```

then create a method like this in First Activity

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(){
   return bitmap;
}
```

and call that function where you required( In other Activities)

```
bitmap_requiredclassname.getBitmap();
```