# How do I pass image to another activity from Listview

Tags: android, android-intent

I got this image from the server. The image is not in the project resource folder. The text is working correctly, but the image is not showing in another activity.

```
    MyAdapter objAdapter1;
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Item item = (Item) objAdapter1.getItem(position);



            Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseDriver.this, DriverDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra(ID, item.getId());
            intent.putExtra(NAME, item.getName().toString());
           intent.putExtra(IMAGE, item.getImage().toString());



            image.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap image= image.getDrawingCache();

             Bundle extras = new Bundle();
           extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
            intent.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: You can see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: intent.putExtra("image",byteArray); should work

Comment: friends I get image from web.not in local resources.So I use this adapter for retrive.any one give solution.

Comment: Show the code for the second Activity where you try to get the image.

Comment: In first Activity,                                                                Item item = (Item) objAdapter1.getItem(position);
 Bitmap bmp =(Bitmap) item.getImage;
 intent.putExtra("YourBitmap", bmp);                                In Second Activity,           
 Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap)intent.getParcelableExtra("YourBitmap");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

**Main Activity:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mItem.getIcon().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
newIntent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
```

**Second Activity:**

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

In FirstActivity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("YourBitmap", bitmap);
```

and in SecondActivity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)intent.getParcelableExtra("YourBitmap");
```

May it help you.