# pass value from one activity to another fails

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

```
Bitmap r = imagelist[args.Position].Data;
byte[] arr = getByteFromBitmap(r);
var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(FullScreenImageViewActivity));
activity2.PutExtra("FullImage", arr);
StartActivity(activity2);
```

I get the correct `byte[]` and put it in the intent. But it never takes me to the other activity so the code below won't be triggered.

```
byte[] b = Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("FullImage");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(b, 0, b.Length);
imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Please check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: I tryied that but somehow it doesn't even start the other activity

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't be using `typeof` in the intent parameters. 
   It should go:

   ```
   var activity2 = new Intent(this, FullScreenImageViewActivity.class);
   ```
2. You're using `putExtra` on a Bitmap, but trying to extract a byte array in the 2nd activity. This will not end well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.....

To Pass Intent..

```
byte[] arr = YOURBYTEARRAY;

Intent intent= new Intent(this, FullScreenImageViewActivity.class);
intent.PutExtra("FullImage", arr);
StartActivity(intent);
```

To Get Intent Value..

```
byte[] b = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("FullImage")
```