# Share bitmap image from one activity to another activity in android

Tags: android

I'm very new for android. In my application I want to share bitmap image one activity to another activity. How can I do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass using `intent.putExtra("data", bitmap`), but this method is costly(memory consuming ).

Answer (score -1):

Pass the following in your First activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);
```

and retrive in your AnotherActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
```

Comment: If the answer is the same as the reported duplicate please don't post it.