# How to handle two different strings in same activity android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I have two different strings in different activity passing in another activity and assigning in  imageview. How to do this?

```
   Activity A:

        Intent intent=new Intent(activity,B.class);
        intent.putExtra("thumb_url", Image); // this is Bitmap
        activity.startActivity(intent);

  Activity C:

      Intent intent = new Intent(activity,B.class);
        intent.putExtra("thumb_urls", images)); //this is String
        activity.startActivity(intent);

 Activity B:

         bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(bundle.containsKey("thumb_url") && bundle.containsKey("thumb_urls")
         {
            Bitmap bitmap=bundle.getParcelable("thumb_url");
            String profile=bundle.getString("thumb_urls");
          }
     I don't know how to assign this in same imageview.

                // bigger_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // how to assign in same imageview for bitmap and string.
               //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(profile, bigger_image); //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` should do the job.

```
 Bitmap bitmap=bundle.getParcelable("thumb_url");
 String profile=bundle.getString("thumb_urls");
 if(bitmap==null && profile!=null)
     imageLoader.DisplayImage(profile, bigger_image);
 else if(bitmap!=null && profile==null)
     bigger_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Also if you are going to receive different content you shouldn't restrict your `if(bundle.containsKey("thumb_url") && bundle.containsKey("thumb_urls")`. You should use a `||` instead of `&&`.

**So the best you can do is:**

```
if(bundle.containsKey("thumb_url"){
  Bitmap bitmap=bundle.getParcelable("thumb_url");
  bigger_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} else if (bundle.containsKey("thumb_urls")){
  String profile=bundle.getString("thumb_urls");
  imageLoader.displayImage(profile, bigger_image); //displayImage instead. DisplayImage doesn't exist.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should't pass a Bitmap in Activity, instead, by using a uri

Comment: You're wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: whatever, passing the entire bitmap requires a lot of memory @Pedro Oliveira