# Size limitation on attached Parcelable?

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, android-bundle

I want to know is there any size limitation on `Parcelable` that attached to an `Intent`? I Read some docs about `Intents`, `Bundles`, `Parcelable` again and there was nothing about size limitation. But I read some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24631097/1043882), that say size of attached `Parcelable` is limited (for example, 1 MB). So are `Parcelable`s limited by size or it only depends to the device?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its explained on the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html). The transaction buffer for each process is 1 mb. In my understanding the factors to be considered are:

1. Individual size of transactions(maximum 1 mb)
2. The number of transactions(the sum of size of all transactions should be less than 1 mb)