# How can i pass the captured photo to an other activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, photo

I have a custom camera app and I want to pass the captured photo into another activity where I can add other icons (emoticons) over it.

How can i pass the captured photo to another activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the photo's URI via an intent. Assuming you call your camera with `startActivityForResult()`. In your camera activity:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFilename);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Then in your emoticon activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null && data.hasExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)) {
        File imageFile = new File(data.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));

        // Bitmap here, do whatever you need
        Bitmap bitmap = readBitmapFromFile(imageFile.getName());
    }
}

public static Bitmap readBitmapFromFile(@NotNull String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me what it is "FileUtils". should i put it as an int or a string or boolean ?

Comment: @Thanks, but  the Intent what should i do with it ? at mainactivity i have an imageview as a button (capture) onClick it calls a method called TakePicture(); from CameraPreview (CameraPreview.TakePicture();) and i have put intent just below this, is it right or no ?