# Difference between passing string and images through intents(in term of memory usage)

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap

In my application, I have several images downloaded from the internet and when I click on those images, the images will be pass to an image viewer (a new activity). In term of memory usage, which is the best way to pass the images to image viewer by using intents? Should I pass the url of the images to the image viewer or pass the bitmaps instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded images, you must send the "Path" of image where it is downloaded using intent. 
From the path received, create a file and make a bitmap of that image.

Comment: So you mean that it is better to send the path of the images instead of the whole bitmap?

Comment: Yaa, passing a string is much better than passing bitmap. 
And what if your image size is large?? 

For more you can refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are likely no difference in memory footprint. `Bitmap` is passed through `Intent` as `Parcelable`, and you can dig into Android SDK source code to find out that only link to it is written.

On the other hand, it'll be safer to pass `String` inside intent in terms of app lifecycle — if the app will be suspended, there can be issues with restoring bitmap from saved intent.