# intent recyclerview with customAdapter image to other activity

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, imageview

Hello I'm trying to intent imageview from `MainActivity` to `DetailActivity` and im using `RecyclerView` with `CustomAdapter` I tried using bitmap, but it didnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it with the intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent(); 
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```