# Pass Bitmap data from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap

My main activity contains the imageview and editactivity has a button for changing the image in imageview .
I used the Intent to startActivityForResult and onActivityResult code is shown below

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();


        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            View mainactivity;


            ImageView imageprofile;
            mainactivity= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
            imageprofile = (ImageView)mainactivity.findViewById(R.id.ProfileImage);


            imageprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The image choosen is not set , please help

Comment: I suggest [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24631097/4168607) from the link above.

Comment: You know that you have to use search before asking, right?

Comment: no its not , whats wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** pass Bitmap to another activity.

Passing the entire bitmap requires a lot of memory

Pass the URI to another activity and load if needed. Hope it helps!

Comment: how should i pass uri , If I use intent I dont want to start the mainactivity , I only want the uri to be passed

Comment: Wrap your URI in Bundle then intent.putExtras(bundle)