# transfer bitmap between two activities in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, bitmap

There are some answers using java in stackoverflow but i am unable to convert it into kotlin code. I am new to kotlin. Please tell me how to transfer bitmap data from one activity to another using Intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the bitmap as an extra argument to the intent while starting the activity.

```kotlin
val intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap)
startActivity(intent);
```

and retrieve it as:

```kotlin
val bitmap = this.intent?.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage") as Bitmap
```

I simply translated the code [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2459624/9529315) to kotlin. You should use Android Studio to translate Java code to Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

I won't recommend you to pass `Bitmap` as `Parcelable` as it may lead to memory and performance issues based on the size of the image.
I would suggest you save the bitmap in a file named `"yourimage"` in the internal storage of your `application` which is not accessible by other apps.

**Saving the bitmap method**

```
fun createImageFromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): String? {
    var fileName: String? = "myImage" //no .png or .jpg needed
    try {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val fo: FileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
        // remember close file output
        fo.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        fileName = null
    }
    return fileName
}
```

**At the receiving activity, get the image to Bitmap variable**

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            context
                .openFileInput("yourimage")
        )
```

Comment: OP asked for passing it through Intents but yes, this is particularly a better solution for bitmaps. +1