# Pass Bitmap image to another activity in Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bitmap

Hi I want to pass bitmap from activity 1 to activity 2. It is a large bitmap and I can not use a bundle. Now I save bitmap and pass path and read a path and load bitmap I do this :

```
val path = saveImage(bitmap)
intent.putExtra("bitmap_path", path)
startActivity(intent)
```

and in activity2

```
val f = File(intent.getStringExtra("bitmap_path"))
val bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.absolutePath)
```

How I can do this better I thing about static object bitmap but I know it is a good practice

edit I do this:

```
class Helper {
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

    companion object {
        val instance = Helper()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488228/transfer-bitmap-between-two-activities-in-kotlin/62488540#62488540

Comment: where did you get the bitmap? I recommend save it to storage and when you need just get it's path to use.

Comment: @NguyễnQuangThọ I crop a photo and past to next activity and show this

Comment: @NguyễnQuangThọ now I do this I edit my post