# I want to send more than two images with intents.(activity to activity)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

This is MainActivity code

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test)
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()

val intent = Intent(this@Math1Activity, test::class.java)
intent.putExtra("image",byteArray)
startActivity(intent)
overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```

This is SecondActivity code

```
val byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image")
if(byteArray != null){
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
    binding.testimage.setImageBitmap(image)
}
```

I want to send more than two images with intents.
But I only know one way to transform a bitmap.
Let me know if there's a good way to intent more than two image.

Comment: from where you will get these images in your First Activity ?note that the max size you can send it is limited chek the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#sdba)

Comment: its not best practice to send images like this through intents, they may be larger in size, you can save them in temporary paths on your device, and later send the path to other activity and clear those temp paths. kindly check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24631097/5088314

Comment: Thank you.
Thanks to you, I solved it well.